# How to find an expiry time of LinkedIn access token?

Tags: php, drupal

i am using LinkedIn access token but it's given that it has an expiry time of 60 days.
i have used the code from [code samples from linkedin developer forum](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples) but i wanted in how many days the access token will expire.can someone help on how to find expiry time of access token.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin oauth Access tokens have a life span of 60 days.

You will get details with getting access token like

```
{"expires_in":5184000,"access_token":"AQXdSP_W41_UPs5ioT_t8HESyODB4FqbkJ8LrV_5mff4gPODzOYR"}
```

The value of parameter **expires_in is the number of seconds** from now that this access_token will expire in **(5184000 seconds is 60 days).**

For more details :- https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: if i get "expires_in" with token, is the any way to store this "expires_in" value locally in a variable so that i can use that value for further calculations.